# iterating row by row through a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking to iterate row by row through a pandas `DataFrame`.  The way I'm doing it so far is as follows:

```
for i in df.index:
    do_something(df.ix[i])
```

Is there a more performant and/or more idiomatic way to do this?  I know about apply, but sometimes it's more convenient to use a for loop.