# Python - KeyError: 14425L

Tags: python, keyerror

When I use this code, it prints everything alright, and then gives me an error:
KeyError: 14425L
The code:

```
i = 0
while (i <= len(data)):
    print data.ix[i]['Params']
    i += 1
```

btw:

```
data.keys()
Out[67]: Index([u'Email Address', u'Hashed Email', u'Timestamp', u'Session Index', u'Event', u'Description', u'Version', u'Platform', u'Device', u'Params'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Why are you looping over indices using an explicit `while` loop? It *must* be possible to use a plain `for` instead(which prevents this kind of errors, and has less overhead).

Comment: What type of object is `data`?

Comment: Iterating by index is unpythonic - it's slow, hard to read, and only works on sequences, not arbitrary iterables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python list indices are 0 based, so `len(data)` is not a valid index.

Use

```
while (i < len(data)):
```

instead.

However, it looks like you are looping over a Pandas dataframe. You may want to review [iterating row by row through a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729210/iterating-row-by-row-through-a-pandas-dataframe) and  [What is the most efficient way to loop through dataframes with pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837722/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-loop-through-dataframes-with-pandas)

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the dumb question :)

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing index past the last one. Maximum index of a list is `len(data) - 1`.

```
while (i <= len(data)):
```

should be:

```
while (i < len(data)):
```