# Pandas : determine mapping from unique rows to original dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following inputs:

```
In [18]: input
Out[18]:
   1  2   3  4
0  1  5   9  1
1  2  6  10  2
2  1  5   9  1
3  1  5   9  1

In [26]: df = input.drop_duplicates()
Out[26]:
   1  2   3  4
0  1  5   9  1
1  2  6  10  2
```

How would I go about getting an array that has the indices of the rows from the subset that are equivalent, eg:

```
resultant = [0, 1, 0, 0]
```

I.e. the '1' here is basically stating that (row[1] in input) == (row[1] in df). Since there will be fewer unique rows than there will be multiple values in 'resultant' that will equate to similar values in df. i.e (row[k] in input == row[k+N] in input) == (row[1] in df) could be a case.

I am looking for actual row number mapping from input:df.

While this example is trivial in my case i have a ton of dropped mappings that might map to one index as an example.

Why do I want this? I am training an autoencoder type system where the target sequence is non-unique.

Comment: I am confused. Do you mean the indices of the duplicate rows dropped?

Comment: The indices within the dropped dataframe where the rows are equal to the rows in the input. Ie: row 0 in df is equal to row 0 in input.

Comment: Updated question for clarity

Comment: Added more info into original question. Does this help? I dont believe that will work because there can be multiple duplicates

Comment: Oh, I got it.  The 0/1 threw me off.  I thought you meant it as boolean but it's just the index number...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to treat it as a `groupby` on all columns:

```
>> df.groupby(list(df.columns)).groups
{(1, 5, 9, 1): [0, 2, 3], (2, 6, 10, 2): [1]}
```

Another would be to `sort` and then compare, which is less efficient in theory but could very well be faster in some cases and is definitely easier to make more tolerant of error:

```
>>> ds = df.sort(list(df.columns))
>>> eqs = (ds != ds.shift()).all(axis=1).cumsum()
>>> ds.index.groupby(eqs)
{1: [0, 2, 3], 2: [1]}
```

This seems the right datastructure to me, but if you really do want an array with the group ids, that's easy too, e.g.

```
>>> eqs.sort_index() - 1
0    0
1    1
2    0
3    0
dtype: int64
```

Comment: This seems more pandas and faster than my suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Don't have pandas installed on this computer, but I think you could use `df.iterrows()` like:

```
def find_matching_row(row, df_slimmed):
    for index, slimmed_row in df_slimmed.iterrows():
        if slimmed_row.equals(row[slimmed_row.columns]):
            return index

def rows_mappings(df, df_slimmed):
    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        yield find_matching_row(row, df_slimmed)

list(rows_mappings(df, input))
```

This is if you are interested in generating the `resultant` list in your example, I don't quite follow the latter part of your reasoning.

Comment: This defiantly works (just need to change == to .equals() ). Is there a more optimal way of doing this though?

Comment: Now bug should be fixed and allows for column dropping. For optimal, if possible, follow the trail at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729210/iterating-row-by-row-through-a-pandas-dataframe